# Error while installing UberCart or Drupal Commerce on Drupal 7.x

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have Drupal 7 and when I am installing modules Ubercart, Rules and Entity API or Drupal Commerce, Rules, Entity API I am getting the following error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;base.owner&#039; in &#039;field        list&#039;: SELECT base.id AS id, base.name AS name, base.label AS label, base.plugin AS plugin, base.active AS active, base.weight AS weight, base.status AS status, base.dirty AS dirty, base.module AS module, base.owner AS owner, base.access_exposed AS access_exposed, base.data AS data FROM {rules_config} base WHERE (base.plugin = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (base.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; reaction rule [:db_condition_placeholder_1] =&gt; 1 ) in EntityAPIController->query() (line 187 of C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.controller.inc).
```

Could you please help me with this kind of error?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstal it and use latest version of modules, something went wrong. I'd recommend using Drupal Commerce insead of D7 + Ubercart since Ubercart is obsolete.

Comment: Τhank you very much!Could you verify that I should do what this article describe? http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/installing-scratch